# Applying a GPO to local users except local administrators on Workgroup computers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a set of configurations which I need to replicate from my domain joined computers to non-domain (Workgroup) joined computers. I created a GPO, enabled Loopback processing and imported them via LGPO.exe (Microsoft Security Compliance Toolkit).
One of the configurations include software restriction policies. I want to restrict normal users accessing the certain file extensions, where as administrators should have full access. On the domain level, it works fine when I apply security filtering for Domain Admins. But on the Workgroup level, it doesn't. The policy gets applied for all the users, including Local Administrators.

I want to make sure that only local users are affected by the user configuration policies.

If I apply a WMI filter to exclude Built-in Local Administrators group, will it work?

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any specific reason why you are not using "Enforcement" under "Software Restriction Policies"?

Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Windows Settings \ Security \ Software Restriction Policies \ Enforcement

[image]